# How to store big matrix(data frame) that can be subsetted easily later

Tags: mysql, database, local-storage, bigdata, storage

I will generate a big matrix(data frame) in R whose size is about 1300000*10000, about 50 GB. I want to store this matrix in a appropriate format, so later I can feed the data into Python or other program codes to make some analysis. Of course I cannot feed the data one time, so I have to subset the matrix and feed them little by little. 
But I don't know how to store the matrix. I think of two ways, but I think neither is appropriate:
(1) plain text(including csv or excel table), because it is very hard to subset(e.g. if I just want some columns and some rows of the data)
(2) database, I have searched information about mysql and sqlite, but it seems that the number of columns is limited in sql database(1024).
So I just want to know if there are any good strategies to store the data, so that I can subset the data by row/column indexes or name.

Comment: nobody knows?

Comment: Do you need to search by any of the 10K columns?  Or just a few of them?

Comment: well,  actually now I need to search by just one columns: every row has a rowname and I just need to subset by rowname/columnname

Answer (score 0):

Have separate column(s) for each of the few columns you need to search/filter on.  Then put the entire 10K columns into some data format that is convenient for the client code to parse.  JSON is one common possibility.

So the table would 1.3M rows and perhaps 3 columns:  an `id` (auto_increment, primary key), the column search on, and the JSON blob - as datatype `JSON` or `TEXT` (depending on software version) for the many data values.